# Best way to view Cisco config file?

Tags: cisco, ios

I just copied the config of our PIX 515 over to a TFTP server. I'm going to need to make some edits to this file before copying it down to a duplicate 515 device. Currently, I'm viewing the config on the TFTP using notepad. It's barely legible. Is there some sort of specialized viewer available that's designed for Cisco config files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Notepad++ with [Cisco ASA syntax highlighter](http://www.linickx.com/archives/875/cisco-asa-syntax-highlighting-with-notepad).